# How to solve the "non-passive event listener ..." google chrome console message

Tags: dom-events, event-listener, passive-event-listeners

I made a wordpress plugin used by slick slider, but the slick github project didnt get update related this chrome warning.I dont want change my plugin and search different slider.So, How can I solve this error in shortest way?

I know there are many question about this issue but this question is **not dublicate** because the answers give same code and I couldnt solve my problem with the code.

What must I do with below code:

```
 addEventListener(document, "touchstart", function(e) {
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented);  // will be false
    e.preventDefault();   // does nothing since the listener is passive
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented);  // still false
  }, Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive: true} : false);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the game, but still:

As many users reported this problem, I integrated a solution into my own fork of slick slider.

To solve the slick slider issue with passive listeners, you can use this fork of slick. It integrates the fix:

https://github.com/nicolaskopp/slick

You can also grab the patch here and use for your own fork, if you like:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/3422

Comment: Can confirm this works, I'm now using Nicolas's fork on all my sites :)